# Metaphorical translation: "To the front/vanguard"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would "To the front/vanguard" be translated not literally but metaphorically? Would there even be a difference?

I am by no means educated in Latin, but I have done some self study. Would "Ad Praeventores" be anywhere close to what I am looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of 'the vanguard' in Latin is actually more commonly idiomatic, as opposed to being a word. If you wanted to say 'to the vanguard', you would actually say '*ad primum agmen*', which means to the first [in] the line of march, when taken literally. Similarly, '*novissimum agmen*' is the rear, as the newest recruits would march at the back of the army. '*Ad praeventores*' would not have any military context, meaning simply 'towards those who proceed'. As to translating metaphorically, I am not entirely sure what you mean - what would be the context of your metaphor?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think Lanet Rino means "translate it as a Roman would."

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer, another common way to refer to the vanguard is *prima acies*.

*In primam aciem* is the usual way of saying, "to the van", e.g. Caesar:

> scuto ab novissimis uni militi detracto, quod ipse eo sine scuto venerat, **in primam aciem processit** centurionibusque nominatim appellatis reliquos cohortatus milites signa inferre et manipulos laxare iussit. (Caesar, *De Bello Gallico* 2.25)

and Livy:

> Praenestinus praetor per timorem segnius ex subsidiis suos duxerat **in primam aciem**. (Livius, *Ab Urbe Condita* 9.16)

I'm not sure what you mean by "not literally but metaphorically." *Acies* is used in a myriad of contexts, some of which are decidedly metaphorical. I am sure that a Roman would understand *in primam aciem* outside of a military context if the context was otherwise clear that it is not meant literally.